# Show access denied page to the user

Tags: 7

I need a function that checks a condition; for example, if `$a == $b` it should return the access denied page to the current user.

What function should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the function which returns the access denied page; that is  [drupal_access_denied()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_access_denied/7). Just call this function inside your conditional statement.